# How does fragment transaction works on navigation UI?

Tags: android

i'm using the Navigation Bottom of Android and i'm trying to understand how section fragments works on it. When should I add a fragment to the transaction? does *appBarConfiguration* add them?

Nav java code

```
    public class BottomNavActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bottom_nav_activity);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_logout, R.id.navigation_dispositivos, R.id.navigation_contactos)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }
}
```

Comment: Navigation does all of the fragment transactions for you. What made you think you have to do any fragment transactions?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have a dialog message, I want to make that when a user click on cancel it pop the fragment backstack